# To equal 2 layout's height in HTML with JQuery

Tags: jquery, css, height, flexbox

I have 2 layouts columns (right and left, left is fluid) which are coordinated by the CSS method Flex-Box. I try to equal their heights. Right layout's height should be same as left layout's height. I put a scroll in right. So I wrote something with JQuery, Although their heights are equal, it doesn't seem equal.

```js
var leftH=$(".left-column").height();

$('.right-column').css('height', (leftH)+'px');

$('.right-column').css('display', 'inline');

alert("Left Height : "+leftH);

alert("Right Height : "+$(".right-column").height());
```

```css
.columns-container{

 display: -webkit-box;

 display: -webkit-flex;

 display: -ms-flexbox;

 display: flex;

 margin:8px auto 5px;

}

.left-column{

-webkit-box-flex:2;

-webkit-flex:2;

    -ms-flex:2;

        flex:2;     
 
}

.right-column{

-webkit-box-flex:1;

-webkit-flex:1;

    -ms-flex:1;

        flex:1;  

overflow-y: scroll;
display: none;

}

.left-column, .right-column{

  border: 1px solid  #ccc; 
  padding: 20px; 
  margin: 8px; 
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px #ccc;
  background: #f8f8f8;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
 <meta charset="UTF-8">
 <title>Document</title>
 <link rel="stylesheet" href="sytle.css">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.3/jquery.min.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
 
<div class="columns-container">

 <div class="left-column">
  
  <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos, natus doloribus modi molestiae, sed facilis corporis voluptatum similique, tempora excepturi in illum aut quam tenetur corrupti sequi dolore fuga ab.</p>
  <p>Doloremque beatae deleniti consequatur dolorem aliquam, amet saepe optio, maiores asperiores commodi nostrum quisquam vero ad est aspernatur odit eligendi repudiandae, facilis illum obcaecati ullam assumenda corporis. Iure, fuga delectus.</p>
  <p>Excepturi similique harum suscipit itaque iusto rem animi vero libero. Consequuntur, fuga, sed tempore ad reprehenderit illum officiis laborum nemo consectetur iste ducimus, nam saepe maxime. Reprehenderit ipsum esse, dolor!</p>
  <p>Id, pariatur dicta quisquam harum accusantium officia enim laudantium aliquid maiores soluta dolore exercitationem omnis debitis vel. Deleniti fugiat delectus eum, quaerat repellat, atque molestiae incidunt, aspernatur, tempora sequi reiciendis.</p>
  <p>Dolor, praesentium. Eos reprehenderit officiis eligendi, expedita tempora sint aliquid cumque vitae natus eius consequatur, quas nostrum similique autem quae in quos error animi? Laboriosam blanditiis quia sunt delectus, iusto.</p>
  <p>Veritatis provident ratione placeat aspernatur molestias temporibus. Quibusdam quaerat dignissimos, ullam laudantium incidunt voluptates ea laboriosam. Dolore necessitatibus rem a corporis pariatur assumenda nesciunt, veritatis quae quasi amet? Repudiandae, dolor.</p>
  <p>Possimus dignissimos illo qui eaque, porro quis. Quos voluptatibus inventore incidunt tempora nesciunt voluptas nihil aspernatur tempore laudantium, sunt eos recusandae nostrum ipsa repellendus molestias, blanditiis error illum! Veniam, voluptatibus?</p>
  <p>Assumenda nulla earum voluptas vero distinctio officia nobis laudantium quae. Voluptas, earum porro laborum autem, iure commodi repellendus esse, iusto perferendis numquam fugiat aperiam nesciunt. Hic eius ea quod, minima?</p>
  <p>Aliquid vitae facilis nisi, rerum nihil quo similique illo eveniet pariatur eaque repudiandae sed, aliquam nostrum assumenda, officiis quasi eius laudantium, accusantium ut. Tenetur laboriosam, illo in, consequatur aliquid odio?</p>
  <p>Reprehenderit alias saepe quae nostrum, quasi quaerat maiores. Illum, libero distinctio iusto, ab laudantium repudiandae necessitatibus voluptas magni eligendi suscipit placeat nobis vel veritatis? Perspiciatis facilis eligendi voluptas tenetur. Dolorum!</p>
           
 </div>
 
 <div class="right-column">
      <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos, natus doloribus modi molestiae, sed facilis corporis voluptatum similique, tempora excepturi in illum aut quam tenetur corrupti sequi dolore fuga ab.</p>
  <p>Doloremque beatae deleniti consequatur dolorem aliquam, amet saepe optio, maiores asperiores commodi nostrum quisquam vero ad est aspernatur odit eligendi repudiandae, facilis illum obcaecati ullam assumenda corporis. Iure, fuga delectus.</p>
  <p>Excepturi similique harum suscipit itaque iusto rem animi vero libero. Consequuntur, fuga, sed tempore ad reprehenderit illum officiis laborum nemo consectetur iste ducimus, nam saepe maxime. Reprehenderit ipsum esse, dolor!</p>
  <p>Id, pariatur dicta quisquam harum accusantium officia enim laudantium aliquid maiores soluta dolore exercitationem omnis debitis vel. Deleniti fugiat delectus eum, quaerat repellat, atque molestiae incidunt, aspernatur, tempora sequi reiciendis.</p>
  <p>Dolor, praesentium. Eos reprehenderit officiis eligendi, expedita tempora sint aliquid cumque vitae natus eius consequatur, quas nostrum similique autem quae in quos error animi? Laboriosam blanditiis quia sunt delectus, iusto.</p>
  <p>Veritatis provident ratione placeat aspernatur molestias temporibus. Quibusdam quaerat dignissimos, ullam laudantium incidunt voluptates ea laboriosam. Dolore necessitatibus rem a corporis pariatur assumenda nesciunt, veritatis quae quasi amet? Repudiandae, dolor.</p>
  <p>Possimus dignissimos illo qui eaque, porro quis. Quos voluptatibus inventore incidunt tempora nesciunt voluptas nihil aspernatur tempore laudantium, sunt eos recusandae nostrum ipsa repellendus molestias, blanditiis error illum! Veniam, voluptatibus?</p>
  <p>Assumenda nulla earum voluptas vero distinctio officia nobis laudantium quae. Voluptas, earum porro laborum autem, iure commodi repellendus esse, iusto perferendis numquam fugiat aperiam nesciunt. Hic eius ea quod, minima?</p>
  <p>Aliquid vitae facilis nisi, rerum nihil quo similique illo eveniet pariatur eaque repudiandae sed, aliquam nostrum assumenda, officiis quasi eius laudantium, accusantium ut. Tenetur laboriosam, illo in, consequatur aliquid odio?</p>
  <p>Reprehenderit alias saepe quae nostrum, quasi quaerat maiores. Illum, libero distinctio iusto, ab laudantium repudiandae necessitatibus voluptas magni eligendi suscipit placeat nobis vel veritatis? Perspiciatis facilis eligendi voluptas tenetur. Dolorum!</p>
 </div>

</div>

</body>
</html>
```

I had to write the code `display:none;` in CSS for the right-column because when the page is loaded, the left-column's height becomes equal to the right-column's height, and a lot of space occur in the left column that I don't want. Since the right column is thinner than left-column, the right-column is taller than the left one. Therefore, left one's height is equal to right one's height.

I want to make right one's height equal to the left one's.

**EDIT:   Problem was solved by Neverwinter (thanks), but when I try to open it with Firefox, problem is still there. Weird thing is that when I refresh the page in firefox, the problem disappears, everything seems fine. I was just wondering that is there any bug in Firefox?? (Firefox version:40.0.2)**

Comment: looks equal to me. both the alerts are same

Comment: Yes alert are same, it means they have to be same height, but I see that their heights are not same. End of the page you can see right one shorter than left.

Comment: Hm... don't have experience with flex-box, but could you use some other CSS? If i understand correctly, jQuery should calculate left box height (maximum height - auto), and apply it to right box/column, which will have scroll?

Comment: Creating 2 layouts page is very easy with flex box, therefore I use it, "Nevermind" yes you understand correctly, First time, right column display is none, JQuery calculate left's height and apply it to right column and it changes right's display property. The weird thing is that when I run snippet and click full page button (after alerts) their heights seem same, if I don't click full page their heights seem different. Anyway their heights dont seem same on the browsers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Define height in left column (100%):

```
.left-column{

-webkit-box-flex:2;

-webkit-flex:2;

    -ms-flex:2;

        flex:2; 
    height:100%;  

}
```

Now you have desired behavior. However, to keep it when browser is resized (if you need it), you will need to call function for equaling heights on window resize... And - don't use display:none!, i forgot, for second column... and, of course - no need for jquery setting of css display:inline, consequently...

And, of course - demo: http://jsfiddle.net/poupu49z/

Answer (score 1):

The problem is when you use

`var leftH=$(".left-column").height();`

your left column have full width because your `right-column` has `display: none` so when you set

`$('.right-column').css('display', 'inline');`

it take some width, so the width of `.left-column` decrease and due to that the `.right-column` height increases that is the reason of its different heights and you can't remove `display:none` on `.left-column` because happens what you said.

If you can prescind of the use of flexbox you can use this:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    setHeight();

    $(window).resize(function(){
        setHeight();
    })
});

function setHeight(){
    $('.right-column').css('height', $(".left-column").outerHeight());
}
```

```css
*{
    box-sizing: border-box;
}
.columns-container {
  margin:8px auto 5px;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.left-column {
  width: calc(66% - 16px);  /* 2/3 (similar to flex: 2) of width minus the margin */
  float: left;
}
.right-column {
  width:  calc(33% - 16px);  /* 1/3 (similar to flex: 1) of width minus the margin */
  overflow-y: scroll;
  float: right;
}
.left-column, .right-column {
  border: 1px solid #ccc;
  padding: 20px;
  margin: 8px;
  border-radius: 5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 1px 1px #ccc;
  background: #f8f8f8;
  display: inline-block;
  vertical-align: top;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="columns-container">
    <div class="left-column">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos, natus doloribus modi molestiae, sed facilis corporis voluptatum similique, tempora excepturi in illum aut quam tenetur corrupti sequi dolore fuga ab.</p>
        <p>Doloremque beatae deleniti consequatur dolorem aliquam, amet saepe optio, maiores asperiores commodi nostrum quisquam vero ad est aspernatur odit eligendi repudiandae, facilis illum obcaecati ullam assumenda corporis. Iure, fuga delectus.</p>
        <p>Excepturi similique harum suscipit itaque iusto rem animi vero libero. Consequuntur, fuga, sed tempore ad reprehenderit illum officiis laborum nemo consectetur iste ducimus, nam saepe maxime. Reprehenderit ipsum esse, dolor!</p>
        <p>Id, pariatur dicta quisquam harum accusantium officia enim laudantium aliquid maiores soluta dolore exercitationem omnis debitis vel. Deleniti fugiat delectus eum, quaerat repellat, atque molestiae incidunt, aspernatur, tempora sequi reiciendis.</p>
        <p>Dolor, praesentium. Eos reprehenderit officiis eligendi, expedita tempora sint aliquid cumque vitae natus eius consequatur, quas nostrum similique autem quae in quos error animi? Laboriosam blanditiis quia sunt delectus, iusto.</p>
        <p>Veritatis provident ratione placeat aspernatur molestias temporibus. Quibusdam quaerat dignissimos, ullam laudantium incidunt voluptates ea laboriosam. Dolore necessitatibus rem a corporis pariatur assumenda nesciunt, veritatis quae quasi amet? Repudiandae, dolor.</p>
        <p>Possimus dignissimos illo qui eaque, porro quis. Quos voluptatibus inventore incidunt tempora nesciunt voluptas nihil aspernatur tempore laudantium, sunt eos recusandae nostrum ipsa repellendus molestias, blanditiis error illum! Veniam, voluptatibus?</p>
        <p>Assumenda nulla earum voluptas vero distinctio officia nobis laudantium quae. Voluptas, earum porro laborum autem, iure commodi repellendus esse, iusto perferendis numquam fugiat aperiam nesciunt. Hic eius ea quod, minima?</p>
        <p>Aliquid vitae facilis nisi, rerum nihil quo similique illo eveniet pariatur eaque repudiandae sed, aliquam nostrum assumenda, officiis quasi eius laudantium, accusantium ut. Tenetur laboriosam, illo in, consequatur aliquid odio?</p>
        <p>Reprehenderit alias saepe quae nostrum, quasi quaerat maiores. Illum, libero distinctio iusto, ab laudantium repudiandae necessitatibus voluptas magni eligendi suscipit placeat nobis vel veritatis? Perspiciatis facilis eligendi voluptas tenetur. Dolorum!</p>
    </div>
    <div class="right-column">
        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipisicing elit. Quos, natus doloribus modi molestiae, sed facilis corporis voluptatum similique, tempora excepturi in illum aut quam tenetur corrupti sequi dolore fuga ab.</p>
        <p>Doloremque beatae deleniti consequatur dolorem aliquam, amet saepe optio, maiores asperiores commodi nostrum quisquam vero ad est aspernatur odit eligendi repudiandae, facilis illum obcaecati ullam assumenda corporis. Iure, fuga delectus.</p>
        <p>Excepturi similique harum suscipit itaque iusto rem animi vero libero. Consequuntur, fuga, sed tempore ad reprehenderit illum officiis laborum nemo consectetur iste ducimus, nam saepe maxime. Reprehenderit ipsum esse, dolor!</p>
        <p>Id, pariatur dicta quisquam harum accusantium officia enim laudantium aliquid maiores soluta dolore exercitationem omnis debitis vel. Deleniti fugiat delectus eum, quaerat repellat, atque molestiae incidunt, aspernatur, tempora sequi reiciendis.</p>
        <p>Dolor, praesentium. Eos reprehenderit officiis eligendi, expedita tempora sint aliquid cumque vitae natus eius consequatur, quas nostrum similique autem quae in quos error animi? Laboriosam blanditiis quia sunt delectus, iusto.</p>
        <p>Veritatis provident ratione placeat aspernatur molestias temporibus. Quibusdam quaerat dignissimos, ullam laudantium incidunt voluptates ea laboriosam. Dolore necessitatibus rem a corporis pariatur assumenda nesciunt, veritatis quae quasi amet? Repudiandae, dolor.</p>
        <p>Possimus dignissimos illo qui eaque, porro quis. Quos voluptatibus inventore incidunt tempora nesciunt voluptas nihil aspernatur tempore laudantium, sunt eos recusandae nostrum ipsa repellendus molestias, blanditiis error illum! Veniam, voluptatibus?</p>
        <p>Assumenda nulla earum voluptas vero distinctio officia nobis laudantium quae. Voluptas, earum porro laborum autem, iure commodi repellendus esse, iusto perferendis numquam fugiat aperiam nesciunt. Hic eius ea quod, minima?</p>
        <p>Aliquid vitae facilis nisi, rerum nihil quo similique illo eveniet pariatur eaque repudiandae sed, aliquam nostrum assumenda, officiis quasi eius laudantium, accusantium ut. Tenetur laboriosam, illo in, consequatur aliquid odio?</p>
        <p>Reprehenderit alias saepe quae nostrum, quasi quaerat maiores. Illum, libero distinctio iusto, ab laudantium repudiandae necessitatibus voluptas magni eligendi suscipit placeat nobis vel veritatis? Perspiciatis facilis eligendi voluptas tenetur. Dolorum!</p>
    </div>
</div>
```

Notice that even when you resize the width of the window it auto adjust.

[**Here a working jsfiddle to play with**](http://jsfiddle.net/Yandy_Viera/0sg7wx9a/)

Comment: Thanks Yandy, I have two solutions now.